# I want to set only once setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, include

I use "include" XML. I do not want to set each "activity" setOnItemClickListener.

My "include" XML food.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/foot"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#292929"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/categories" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and where I set him

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#595858"
    android:gravity="top" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/foot">

    <include
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        layout="@layout/foot" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

every time the my activity uses "foot" I set on my image "setOnItemClickListener"

**I want to set only once setOnItemClickListener**

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make all your activities inherit from a base activity class that will set the listener if the imageview with the appropriate ID exists:

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {
    public onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      ImageView clickableImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
      if (clickableImageView!=null) clickableImageView .setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
      // ...
    };
}
```

Comment: where I have to specify " public onStart()" ?

Comment: good practice to set them to null ? hmm... I don't remember to have seen this anywhere?

Comment: "I don't remember to have seen this anywhere?" - Do not make fun =) I'm a beginner ...

Answer (score 2):

You must to code separate class with `setOnItemClickListener` realization and after that extend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the onclick function in xml like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/categories"
        android:onClick="callThisOnClick" />
```

Then in your activity you have

```
public void callThisOnClick(View v){
        // put your onClick code here.
}
```

You have to remember that android will only look in the current activity for callThisOnclick so you have to include it in every activity that uses food.

You can use a base class that extends activity and has callThisOnClick then extend your base class with the rest of your activities.